# Read coordinates of points three by three from a text file with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate the angle using data from a text file. 
Right now, I have a python code which can calculate the angle.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([27.090, 26.790, 4.920])
b = np.array([26.790, 26.400, 5.740])
c = np.array([27.490, 26.590, 6.370])

ba = a - b
bc = c - b

cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)

print np.degrees(angle)
```

But i want this python code should take coordinates from a text file (`coord.txt`). Because I have multiple coordinates in the text file like

```
27.090 26.790 4.920
26.790 26.400 5.740
27.490 26.590 6.370
```

Format of text file is `x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 x3 y3 z3` for each line and it should give angle corresponding to each line.

Code should consider coordinate from text file and write angle in another text file.

Comment: Are each of the coordinates within the coordinate groups on separate lines in the text file and is there a blank line that separates each of the coordinate groups?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
with open(filename) as infile:
    data = [map(float, i.split()) for i in infile.readlines()]
    data = [map(np.array, [j[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(j), 3)]) for j in data]    

for i in data:
    print i
```

**Output:**

```
[array([ 27.09,  26.79,   4.92]), array([ 26.79,  26.4 ,   5.74]), array([ 27.49,  26.59,   6.37])]
[array([ 1.239,  2.36 ,  4.56 ]), array([ 2.34,  4.56,  6.9 ]), array([ 2.35,  6.98,  9.07])]
```

*Edit as per comment*

```
import numpy as np

def getAngle(a, b, c):
    ba = a - b
    bc = c - b
    cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)
    return np.degrees(angle)

with open(filename) as infile:
    data = [map(float, i.split()) for i in infile.readlines()]
    data = [map(np.array, [j[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(j), 3)]) for j in data]

for i in data:
    a, b, c =  i
    print(getAngle(a, b, c))
```

Comment: but code is not working. I have given filename coord.txt in your python code but it is not working.

Comment: that python code should give angle also corresponding to that coordinates.

Comment: yes i am getting error                                                                             "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 2, in <module>
    with open(coord.txt) as infile:
NameError: name 'coord' is not defined"

Comment: `with open("coord.txt") as infile`

Comment: yes it's working... but i want code should give angle between three points it should read from text file. if you can do that. I have wrote down code above which can calculate angle between three points.

Comment: Updated snippet

Comment: File "angle_final.py", line 15, in <module>
    a, b, c =  i
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
I have compile this program...that you have updated but above error is coming.

Comment: What does `i` print?

Comment: @claudiasmith Both answers are working with the data you provided. Thus I upvoted both. You need to implement the answers in your code on your own. This should be easy. No one knows what your data really looks like. Only you can do that.

Comment: @Rakesh print is printing coordinate like your first code was doing. After your edited code I am trying to calculate the angle between three points a,b,c like three array in i. but for i in data: 'a,b,c =i ' is not taking i guess. thats why not calculating angle. As you can see in my program it was working fine if i was providing coordinate in a, b, c manually. but i have huge number of coordinate that is why i want coordinate should be read from text file. and then calculate the angle.

Answer (score 1):

If you text file is like this(every line has three data and was split by whitespace):

```
27.090 26.790 4.920
26.790 26.400 5.740
27.490 26.590 6.370
```

then you can try this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

coord = []
with open("coord.txt", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        coord.append(line[0].split(' '))

for i, line in enumerate(coord):
    for j, value in enumerate(line):
        coord[i][j] = float(value)

print(coord)
```